# Can I install unrtf in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, rtf

I'm using Python 2.7 and am trying to use Textract to scrape information from rtf files. For this to work, I also need to install unrtf. When I try to install it, I get an error saying that it only works for Python 3.x. So is there a way to install unrtf is Python 2.x?

Or are there other alternatives to scraping information from rtf files?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to use Python 2?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's just what I have been using.

Comment: Then I think in your scenario it would be easier to switch to Python 3 (of course running your source files through [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/2to3.html) to ensure compatibility), than to find the perfect configuration of Python 2-compatible packages that do what you want. It isn't ideal, but if you're not picky about Python versions, this should be easier.